# Objective-C I can access self.view but not self.view.frame

Tags: objective-c, uiview

I can access and show self.view and see the frame in the log but when I try to access self.view.frame  I get null. Below is the log output of

```
NSLog(@"Show self.view:%@",self.view);
NSLog(@"Show self.view.frame:%@",self.view.frame);
```

-

```
2010-03-28 11:08:43.373 vivmed_CD_Tab[20356:207] Show self.view:<UITableView: 0x4001600; frame = (0 0; 320 583); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x3b21270>>
2010-03-28 11:08:43.373 vivmed_CD_Tab[20356:207] Show self.view.frame:(null)
```

Can anyone explain why `self.view.frame` is `null` but `self.view` shows a frame? My goal is to change the frame size.

Cheers,
Grant

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One problem in the code you've posted is that you're printing the frame (a `CGRect`) as an object, which won't work. Try:

```
NSLog(@"Show self.view.frame: %u", self.view.frame);  // as a pointer

NSLog(@"Show self.view.frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.view.frame));  // as a string
```

Comment: That's right!  The first two fields of the CGRect would be zero, so the Obj-C runtime interprets it as an object with a null class pointer.  If the frame had a different origin, you'd be crashing.